# Install mysql workbench on debian wheezy amd64

Tags: debian-wheezy, mysql-workbench

I try install mysql workbench on debian wheezy amd64 but there are many dependencies:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   mysql-workbench : Depends: libctemplate2 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libtinyxml2.6.2 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 5.2.40+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be       installed
               Depends: python-mysql.connector but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ttf-bitstream-vera but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-workbench-gpl : Depends: libctemplate0 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libmysqlclient16 (>= 5.1.21-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libzip1 (>= 0.8) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try install that libs I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libzip1
...
Package libzip1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libzip1' has no installation candidate
```

Is another ways to install mysql-workbench? I also downloaded deb-files and sources - but no success.

P.S.

My sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20130504- 14:43]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20130504-14:43]/ wheezy main

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Comment: Could you post your `sources.list` file? Have you run `apt-get update` recently?

Comment: Done. >Have you run apt-get update recently? - Yes, I did.

Comment: I have already installed mysql workbench by downloading this deb-file http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench_5.2.40+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...

Answer (score 3):

From your source.list it seems that you only contain the 'main' component. Some packages are under 'contrib' componet, ans that is the reason apt-get can not install some packages (since in apt-get's package DB there is no record for those packages).

Please read Debian Wiki page https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList to moditfy your source.list and do `apt-get update'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL docs page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#repo-qg-apt-available) MySQL Workbench is not supported on Debian platforms (emphasis added):

> `mysql-workbench-community`: MySQL Workbench (**not available for Debian platforms**)